# C++ std::conditional_t wont compile with std::is_enum_v and std::underlying_type_t

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, type-traits

I am trying to wite type traits for types that can index into e.g. an `std::vector`, which should include enum types because i can cast them to their underlying type.

I have written following traits so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct is_unsigned_integral :
    std::integral_constant<
        bool,
        std::is_integral<T>::value &&
        std::is_unsigned<T>::value
    > {};

template<typename T>
inline constexpr auto is_unsigned_integral_v = 
    is_unsigned_integral<T>::value;

template<typename, typename = void>
struct is_index : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_index<
    T, 
    std::enable_if_t<
        is_unsigned_integral_v<
            std::conditional_t<
                std::is_enum_v<T>,
                std::underlying_type_t<T>,
                T
            >
        >
    >
> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
inline constexpr auto is_index_v = is_index<T>::value;

enum class idx : unsigned int {};

int main() {
    static_assert(is_index_v<unsigned int>, "");
    static_assert(is_index_v<idx>, "");
    
    return 0;
}
```

But im getting following error message

```
type_traits:2009:15: error: 
      only enumeration types have underlying types
      typedef __underlying_type(_Tp) type;
```

I would expect the following

```
std::conditional_t<
    std::is_enum_v<T>,
    std::underlying_type_t<T>,
    T
>
```

to evaluate eighter to `T` or to underlying type is `T` is an `enum`.

How would i make this work?

Comment: out of curiosity, what compiler are you using? With gcc the static assert fails (and the reason is what your error message says, but it should not be an error because of SFINAE) https://godbolt.org/z/cs7Gbjc3n

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number is used clang while playing around in [replit.com](https://replit.com/languages/cpp). Im currently trying to get more comfortable with type traits and meta programming :)

Comment: also with clang I get a different error https://godbolt.org/z/xn5PfscPG, though I am actually not sure what is guaranteed since `std::underlying_type<T>` is UB until C++20 when `T` is not an enum,

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I have tried your answer in other online compiler using gcc / clang and it seems to work fine under gcc but clang still gives an error

Comment: no errors here with clang https://godbolt.org/z/Tqe8YG3vT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substitution fails because there is no `std::underlying_type_t<unsigned int>`.

You can specialize seperately:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct is_unsigned_integral :
    std::integral_constant<
        bool,
        std::is_integral<T>::value &&
        std::is_unsigned<T>::value
    > {};

template<typename T>
inline constexpr auto is_unsigned_integral_v = 
    is_unsigned_integral<T>::value;

template<typename, typename = void>
struct is_index : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_index<
    T, 
    std::enable_if_t< is_unsigned_integral_v<T> >    
> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_index<T,std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<T> >> : is_index<std::underlying_type_t<T> > {};


template<typename T>
inline constexpr auto is_index_v = is_index<T>::value;

enum class idx : unsigned int {};

int main() {
    static_assert(is_index_v<unsigned int>, "");
    static_assert(is_index_v<idx>, "");
    
    return 0;
}
```

---

PS: From [cppreference/std::underlying_type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type)

> If T is a complete enumeration (enum) type, provides a member typedef type that names the underlying type of T.
>
> Otherwise, the behavior is undefined. (until C++20)
>
> Otherwise, if T is not an enumeration type, there is no member type. Otherwise (T is an incomplete enumeration type), the program is ill-formed.
> (since C++20)

I have to admit that I am not sure how that undefined beahvior (before C++20) plays with SFINAE in your example. Though, note that it is not an issue in the above, because it only uses `std::underlying_type_t<T>` when `T` is actually an enum type.

Comment: thanks for this very elegant solution. Works as expected!